# How to access user-context data set on epoll when calling epoll_wait

Tags: c++

Below I add sockets to epoll and set an application-context index within `epoll_event.data.u32`.

When receiving packets, `recv()` requires the socket file descriptor. In all the examples  `events[i].data.fd` is used.

However, `events[i].data.fd` and `events[i].data.u32` are in a union, so how do I also access my user-context index `events[i].data.u32`? It looks like it is overwritten with the socket file descriptor?

```
// Initially
int epollFd = epoll_create1(0);

// Adding each socket, along with a user-context index for callbacks
struct epoll_event event;
event.events = EPOLLIN;
event.data.u32 = callbackIndex; // Here is the user-defined index
int sock = createSocket(port, address);
assert(epoll_ctl(epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sock, &event));

// Later when receiving packets

struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];

while (true)
{
    int event_count = epoll_wait(epollFd, events, MAX_EVENTS, 30000);
            
    for (i = 0; i < event_count; i++)
    {
        int n = recv(events[i].data.fd, &buffer[0], sizeof(buffer), flags);
        // How do I access the user-context index I set when adding the socket to epoll?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell `epoll_ctl()` which socket descriptor you want to listen for events for, and provide an `epoll_event` struct to associate with that listen operation.

Whenever `epoll_wait()` detects a registered event on a socket, it gives you back *only* the `epoll_event` struct that you had provided for that event, exactly as you had provided it. It *does not* tell you which socket triggered the event.

So, if you want to discover the socket, you have to either:

- store the socket descriptor itself in the `epoll_event`, but then you can't use any other user-defined data.
- store the socket descriptor somewhere else (ie, in an array, an object pool, etc) and then put identifying information needed to get back to the socket descriptor as user-defined data in the `epoll_event` (ie, array index, object pointer, etc).

Whatever you put in the `epoll_event` when calling `epoll_ctl()` is what you will get back from `epoll_wait()`. No more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

Design of epoll is beautifully simple. The role of `epoll_data_t` is to provide lightweight *mapping* rather than *storage*. Notice that it has a `void* ptr` member, which allows you to map from `fd` (passed to `epoll_ctl`) to *anything*.

In your particular case, you could allocate a `struct Context { int fd; uint32_t index; /*...*/ };` on the heap and point to that structure on `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`. You would have to also deallocate it after calling `EPOLL_CTL_DEL` by some object (e.g. container) which *owns* that context.

Since you are using C++, you could store a pointer to an abstract `EventListener` base class, `reinterpret_cast` from `void*` after `epoll_wait` to that class and dispatch event to an arbitrary derived handler.